Why is my pg_basebackup incompatible with Postgres?
I have a backup shell script which runs pg_basebackup every night. When I try to run it though I get this error message saying that pg_basebackup is apparently not compatible with Postgres.app version 16.3.
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - Backup script started.
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - PG_USER: postgres
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - BACKUP_DIR: /Volumes/Atoma/Backup
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - TEMP_BACKUP_DIR: /Volumes/Atoma/tmp_backup
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - DAY_OF_WEEK: Donnerstag
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - BACKUP_NAME: Donnerstag.tar.gz
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - LOG_FILE: /Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.log
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - Starting backup for Donnerstag.
2024-07-25 14:38:37 - Running pg_basebackup command.
pg_basebackup: error: incompatible server version 16.3 (Postgres.app)
pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "/Volumes/Atoma/tmp_backup"
2024-07-25 14:38:38 - Backup failed for Donnerstag.
2024-07-25 14:38:38 - Backup script finished.

I use macOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79). This is my backup script:
#!/bin/zsh


# Variables
PG_USER="xyz"
PG_USER_PW="xyz"
PORT="5432"
HOST="localhost"

BACKUP_DIR="/Volumes/Atoma/Backup"
TEMP_BACKUP_DIR="/Volumes/Atoma/tmp_backup"
DAY_OF_WEEK=$(date +%A)
BACKUP_NAME="$DAY_OF_WEEK.tar.gz"
LOG_FILE="/Users/tristan/Server_Backup/daily.log"

# create temporary directory (needed for pg_basebackup)
mkdir -p $TEMP_BACKUP_DIR

# log with timestamp
log_with_timestamp() {
  echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - $1" >> $LOG_FILE
}

# Start logging
log_with_timestamp "Backup script started."

# Logging variables
log_with_timestamp "PG_USER: $PG_USER"
log_with_timestamp "BACKUP_DIR: $BACKUP_DIR"
log_with_timestamp "TEMP_BACKUP_DIR: $TEMP_BACKUP_DIR"
log_with_timestamp "DAY_OF_WEEK: $DAY_OF_WEEK"
log_with_timestamp "BACKUP_NAME: $BACKUP_NAME"
log_with_timestamp "LOG_FILE: $LOG_FILE"

# Start backup log process
log_with_timestamp "Starting backup for $DAY_OF_WEEK."

# Set the PGPASSWORD environment variable
export PGPASSWORD=$PG_USER_PW

# Run pg_basebackup
log_with_timestamp "Running pg_basebackup command."
if pg_basebackup -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $PG_USER -D $TEMP_BACKUP_DIR -Ft -z -P -Xs 2>> $LOG_FILE; then
    # Compress the backup and move it to the final destination
    mv $TEMP_BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME $BACKUP_DIR
    log_with_timestamp "Backup completed successfully for $DAY_OF_WEEK."
else
    log_with_timestamp "Backup failed for $DAY_OF_WEEK."
fi

# Clean up temporary backup directory
rm -rf $TEMP_BACKUP_DIR

# Unset the PGPASSWORD environment variable for security
unset PGPASSWORD

# End of script
log_with_timestamp "Backup script finished."


pgbasebackup version number must match postgresql version number.

But how can I make sure that both are on the same version? I just reinstalled Postgres.app and if I run /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/16/bin/pg_basebackup -V it returns pg_basebackup (PostgreSQL) 16.3 (Postgres.app). pg_basebakup is installed with the Postgres application so they should have the same version, right?

I would expect them to yes.

Could it be that pg_basebackup isn't being updated anymore?

I'm not going to speculate.  maybe someone else has an answer.

I had PostgreSQL 14 and 15 installed with homebrew and my script took the pg_basebackup from the homebrew installation which was obviously the wrong version.
I just uninstalled the homebrew version of Postgres brew uninstall postgresql@14 and brew uninstall postgresql@15 and after that brew cleanup.
Then I added the bin folder in Postgres.app to the PATHexport PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH and put it at the top of my script.
